# What are our options to use GSuite and GCP (or otherwise NOT use SQL and Windows Server) as a domain controller?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-compute-engine, domaincontroller

Our company is using the GCP and GSuite. We have 500+ employees and are about to set up a domain controller.

This is because our IT "consultant" is suggesting that we do so. However, I feel that we can figure out a better way. Currently we are operating without any on prem servers, as we use SaaS for all 3rd party systems, and as I mentioned GCP and GSuite. We have 13+ locations across one state currently and growing; and thus a full amount of devices (mac, pc, droid, iphone, ipad, linux).

- What are our options to use GSuite and GCP (or otherwise NOT use SQL and Windows Server) as a domain controller?
- Maybe using Cloud SQL and a Microsoft Server on a VM instance in GCP? Ive seen sites that advertise cloud based DC services, what are your thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in implementing a Cloud SQL and a Microsoft Server on a Compute Engine instance in the Google Cloud Platform or on AWS instances there are these documents from the official documentations that you might find interesting:

- [Deploying a Fault-Tolerant Microsoft Active Directory Environment on
  GPC](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/deploy-fault-tolerant-active-directory-environment)
- [Deploy and Manage Your Own AD DS on AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quickstart/latest/active-directory-ds/architecture.html)

Since so far your infrastructure is at the moment totally cloud based I would carry on with this approach and avoid to make use of an on premise solution merely for the Active Directory and the domain controller. I consider the cloud solution way more fault tolerant, reliable and available but you might face some kind of limitations if you want to implement something that it is not "standard" (that is basically ).

However consider that this is a really complex matter and the best solution depends a lot on your current infrastructure.